# ネームサーバ(DNSコンテンツサーバ)のAレコードのIP変更した場合の質問

Tags: aws, dns

WEBサーバをたててサイトを運用しています。
AWSでEC2を二つ(Aサーバ、Bサーバ)作成し、どちらにもElastic IP(固定IP)を設定しました。
また、お名前.comでドメイン名を発行し、ネームサーバ(DNSコンテンツサーバ)のAレコードにAサーバの固定IPを設定し、ドメイン名とAサーバをひもづけました。

ここで、BサーバにWEBの移行をしたいと考えた場合、当然ネームサーバ(DNSコンテンツサーバ)のAレコードのIPアドレスをBサーバのもの変更すると思うのですが、
ここでネームサーバ(DNSコンテンツサーバ)のTTLの値を10分程度に短くすれば、
10分程度でユーザアクセスは新しい方のサーバにアクセスをするということでよろしいでしょうか。

また、もし古い方のサーバにアクセスをした場合、新しい方のサーバに強制的にリダイレクトさせるような処理を行うことは可能でしょうか。(ドメインネームは変更なし)

DBもBサーバのマシンに移行を考えているため、リダイレクトをおこないたく思います.

サーバ移行に関して、初歩的な質問であるとは思いますが、なにとぞご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTLはキャッシュの生存期間ですので 仮に 10分に設定すればキャッシュサーバー10分間は保持します。TTLを10分に変更しても その前のTTLの間は保持されてるでしょうから 変更前のTTLの期間＋10分 で新しいアドレスが参照されると思います。変更前のTTLが1日であれば 最大で 24時間と10分となるかと思います。

並行稼動時にアクセスがA、Bに別れるのがマズイのであれば、EIP を Aサーバーから 外して Bサーバーに取り付ける方式はどうでしょうか。これであれば Aレコードは変更せずに済みますので ほんの僅かな停止時間で 切り替えが可能です。

この方式は クラウドデザインパターンで [CDP:Floating IPパターン](http://aws.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/CDP:Floating_IP%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3) という名前がついてます。DNSレコードを変更するの比べて TTL の制限を回避出来る方法として よく使われてます。

リダイレクトする場合は ブラウザには Bサーバーの EIP がアドレス欄に表示されてしまうでしょうからあまり うまくないですね。

Comment: @take88さん　アドバイスありがとうございます。AサーバのEIP(仮に123.123.123.123)だったとすると、BサーバのEIPを123.123.123.123に変えてしますということですね。(誤解釈だったらすみません)
仮に、サーバ停止をする時間を設けて、もともとのドメイン名(hogehoge.com)をAサーバの方でdev.hogehoge.comとかに変更し、Bサーバをhogehoge.comにした場合(Aレコード変更)、ユーザアクセスは再度DNSコンテンツサーバに名前解決要求を行い、即時にBサーバにアクセスを行いにいくという解釈でよろしいでしょうか。

これも基本的な質問ではあるかと思いますが、なにとぞご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: EIPはEC2インスタンスに「アタッチ」したり「デタッチ」したりできます。サーバーAのEIPを「デタッチ」して、サーバーBに「アタッチ」し直すと グローバルIPはそのままで EC2 インスタンスを交換できるわけです。

Comment: 「即時にBサーバにアクセスを行いにいくか」というご質問ですが、これは TTL によります。TTLの時間内の場合、クライアントは「hogehoge.com」のIPアドレスをDNSキャッシュサーバーに問い合わせ、キャッシュサーバーが サーバーA のIPを返します。TTLが切れるとキャッシュサーバーは コンテンツサーバーに問合せして サーバーBのIPを返します。

Comment: @take88さん
わかりやすい説明ありがとうございます。もう一歩踏み込みたいのですが、これがもし、クラウドの環境でない場合（アタッチ、デタッチができない）、当然上記の例だとTTLが切れるまではサーバAのIPを返し、アクセスはサーバAにいってしまいますが、DBがBサーバにすでに移動している場合、やはりAサーバを再度稼働させてDBの向け先をBサーバのDBにするという方法しかないのでしょうか？物理環境の場合での質問ということになります。

非常にお手数かけますが、なにとぞご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 物理でもIPの付け替えは可能ですしDNSレコードで切り替えることでもサーバー切替えるはできると思います。ポイントになりそうなのは、平行稼働を認めるかどうかと停止を許容できるかだと思います。この辺はいかがですか？

Comment: @take88さん
返答ありがとうございます。平行稼働もサイト停止も許容できます。
また、サイトドメイン名は変わらず、DBサーバが新WEBの環境と
同環境に入るというケースです。

なにとぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 物理環境でipを付け替えるには2通り考えられます。1. AのNICのIPを空いてるNICに変更してBのNICを変更する 2. ルーターでNATしてる場合はグローバルIPの向き先をBのプライベートIPに変更するです。前者はお使いの環境によってはNWスイッチが記憶してるMACアドレスを消す必要があるかもしれません。停止が許容出来るならこの方式のほうが1回で切り替わるので良いと思います。停止が許容出来ないなら平行稼働させてDNSでクライアントからのアクセスをBに向ける必要が出てきます。この場合AからBのDBに接続するのがいいと思います。少なくともTTLが切れるまで、出来ればAへのアクセスが無くなるまで平行稼働させて、最終的にはAを停止させれば切り替わり完了です。

Comment: 補足ですがIP変更による影響の有無は事前によく調査なさってください。Firewallなどのアクセス制御、他のシステムからIPで接続してないか。また、商用のソフトウェアでは IP でライセンス管理しているものもあります。

Comment: 停止が許容できるなら、事前にTTLを60秒など極端に短くしたうえで、TTLが切れるまでサーバーAを止めておくのも 方法として有りだと思います。ルーターやスイッチなど気にしなくていいというのがメリットです。

Comment: 思いつくままにいろいろ書きましたが「これが正解」と言うのは無いので一番都合の良い方法を選んで 見てはどうかと思います～。

Comment: @take88さん　
ありがとうございます。
この点を踏まえて移行の設計をおこなっていきます。
最後にTTLに関して、
下記の手順でサイト移行を行いたいと考えました。

前提：TTLの設定値が3600(1時間)

①旧環境、新環境ともに稼働した状態だが、
どちらもメンテページをみせる
(.htaccessの設定でErrorDocument 503記述)

②メンテページに切り替えたらAレコード、TTLの設定値を変更する
・Aレコードの設定 
旧：hogehoge.jp → XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
新：hogehoge.jp → YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
・TTLの設定値→3600(1時間)から600(10分)に変更

③メンテ中にdig hogehoge.jpでIPが切り替わるまで監視(作業PC等で確認)

この段階で作業PCのdig hogehoge.jpが新環境の方を向いた場合、作業PCに関しては、新IPへの名前解決がされていますが、「一般ユーザ」に関しては各々キャシュの値を保持しているので、最低でも1時間以上のメンテ時間を設け、逆に1時間以上のメンテ時間を設けたのちにサイトを開放した場合は、旧環境へのアクセスは起こらないということでよろしいでしょうか。
旧環境へのアクセスの可能性があるとすればどんな状況でしょうか。

何度もすいませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 基本的にはご認識のとおりでいいと思います。旧環境にアクセスされる可能性としては、経験則ですが家庭用のルーター等で、再起動するまでDNSキャッシュサーバーが変更前のIPを返し続けるというものがありました。またブラウザが独自にキャッシュしていてdigの結果は新しいIPなのにブラウザ経由だと前のIPに繋ぎに行くというケースもありブラウザのキャッシュクリアで解決したことがあります。

Comment: @take88さん
ありがとうございます。
いずれにせよ、なにかの都合で旧サーバにアクセスしにいった場合は、新環境にDB(ここだけが真のデータ)がある場合、旧サーバのDBへのつなぎ先を新環境のDBにアクセスする必要はあるということですね？

お手数おかけしますが、ここもしりたいところなので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: そうですね。AからBのDBに接続すれば良さそうに思います。

Comment: @take88さん

ありがとうございました！